# Split 32-char string into 4 groups of 8

Tags: c++, python, string

I have a string that looks like this:

```
str = "751CEC132EB348978013CE7AF8375137"
```

It is 32 characters long. I want to modify it to look like this:

```
{0x751CEC13,0x2EB34897,0x8013CE7A,0xF8375137}
```

I know that if I can split up the string into 4 groups (8 characters each) I can easily construct the required string using those groups and a stringstream.

An easy way to do this in python would be to do this:

```
'{0x%s,0x%s,0x%s,0x%s}'%(str[0:8],str[8:16], str[16:24], str[24:32])
```

How can I do this in C++? I'm not very familiar with the low level functions like "sscanf" but they sound like they could come in handy.

Comment: is "{0x751CEC13,0x2EB34897,0x8013CE7A,0xF8375137}" a string? or an array of strings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string strarray[4];
strarray[0] = "0x" + str.substr(0, 8);
strarray[1] = "0x" + str.substr(8, 8);
strarray[2] = "0x" + str.substr(16, 8);
strarray[3] = "0x" + str.substr(24, 8);
```

If the `{0x751CEC13,0x2EB34897,0x8013CE7A,0xF8375137}` is a whole string, then use the following lines instead:

```
ostringstream strm;
strm << "{" << "0x" << str.substr(0, 8) << ",0x" << str.substr(8, 8)
            << ",0x" << str.substr(16, 8) << ",0x" << str.substr(24, 8) << "}";
str = strm.str();
```

Comment: Whoops, you beat me to it. Deleting my similar answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I skipped the whole strarray thing completely. I'm still relatively new to C++, but sometimes it's hard to know whether there's a high level solution for what you want to do or you have to resort to something low level. For example, I had to use a wcstombs to generate said string.

Answer (score 4):

It is very similar in C/C++:

```
const char* str = "751CEC132EB348978013CE7AF8375137";
char parts[4][9];
sscanf(str, "%8s%8s%8s%8s", parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
char out[64];
sprintf(out, "0x%s, 0x%s, 0x%s, 0x%s", parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
cout << out << endl;
```

[Link](http://ideone.com/Upxet) to ideone implementation .

Comment: @KirilKirov You're right, it should have been nine (`(32/4)+1`...)